# How do I get the text value of an input box after I send in some input?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am entering some email into a text box and I am trying to trying get the value of the text box (which is suppose to be the email address) but instead I receive: *ClientFunctionResultPromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }*  I am trying to log the output because essentially I want to create an assertion which checks to see if the input box is filled or not.

**mainfile.js**

```
import login from '../pages/login’;
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const logs = new login();

fixture `A Simple Example`
   .page `http://localhost/simple-example`;

test(‘Check email`', async t => {

 logs.enterEmail(”yager@micheal.com");

  });
```

**Login.js file**:

```
export default class Login {
   constructor() {
   this.receiptEmail = Selector("input[copy='Recipient email']");
   }

async enterEmail(email){
  await t.typeText(this.receiptEmail,email);
  console.log(this.receiptEmail.innerText); // I also tried textContent and value and still received the same log
 }

}

<div class="CustomerInfo__fields__field"><label for="recipient-email" class="CustomerInfo__fields__field__label" style="visibility: visible;">Recipient email*</label><input copy="Recipient email" field="email" section="recipient" maxlength="200" class="CustomerInfo__fields__field__input recipient-email " required="" name="email" placeholder="" type="email" value="yager@micheal.com"></div>
```

Can someone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements require a name attribute to have their values passed when the form is submitted. Using the `name` or `id` attribute is the natural way to select the correct form field for testing.

For an input field such as:

```
<input id="email" name="email_address" />
```

it's possible to use either `#email` or `input[name="email_address"]` as the selector string.

Example test case:

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

fixture `A Simple Example`
  .page `http://localhost/simple-example`;

test('Email Input Test', async t => {

  const emailInput = Selector('input[name="email_address"]');
  const emailAddress = 'john.smith@domain.com';

  await t
    .typeText(emailInput, emailAddress)
    .expect(emailInput.value).eql(emailAddress);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The `label` tag for the form field is specified for `recipient-email`, this should correspond to the value for the `id` attribute of the form input field. Your form input tag doesn't have an `id` attribute, adding the attribute simplifies the selector.

You also have a hardcoded `value` property for the field, this will need to be cleared before you add content to the field. The TestCafe API doesn't set the field value to a string directly, instead it simulates a user typing the provided text. So if the input doesn't get cleared automatically, for example after a click on it, you need to simulate the actions of a user removing the text.

```
<div class="CustomerInfo__fields__field">
  <label for="recipient-email" 
         class="CustomerInfo__fields__field__label" 
         style="visibility: visible;">Recipient email*</label>
  <input id="recipient-email"
         copy="Recipient email" field="email" section="recipient" maxlength="200" 
         class="CustomerInfo__fields__field__input recipient-email " required="" 
         name="email" placeholder="" type="email" value="yager@micheal.com" /> 
</div>
```

**login.js:** Remember to import `t` so that TestCafe can do its magic and provide the right test controller.

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

export default class Login {
  constructor () {
    // Use standard CSS selectors to locate elements
    // This selector targets the HTML element with id="recipient-email"
    this.receiptEmail = Selector('#recipient-email');
  }
  async enterEmail(email) {
    // Simulate the clearing of the field first
    await t
      .click(this.receiptEmail)
      .pressKey('ctrl+a delete')
      .typeText(this.receiptEmail, email);

    // Resolve the Selector promise to get the field
    // and console.log the value property
    console.log('receiptEmail: ' + await this.receiptEmail.value);
  }
}
```

**mainfile.js:** Be sure to set the correct URL to the target page for the test fixture and remember to include the port number if it's not the standard port, e.g. http://localhost:3000/.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import login from '../pages/login';

const logs = new login();

// Change the page URL string
// It specifies the target URL to load for the test fixture
fixture `A Simple Example`
  .page `http://localhost/simple-example`;

test('Check email', async t => {
  // You must use 'await'
  await logs.enterEmail('user@unknown.com');

});
```

So in answer to your question, if your `Selector` is valid it will return a Promise which you can resolve to get the HTML field, this will give you access to its `value` property.

TestCafe makes you explicitly use promises and async/await to manage execution of tests.

Comment: Hey Dan , I updated my code. Basically I am taking the input (aka email address) from the fixture and passing it into a login function in a different file (called login.js).

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML for the form? I can update my answer when I know exactly what we're dealing with in the form.

Comment: Hi Akeem, I've updated my answer to make it as detailed as possible for you.